# LINQ `Any` not covered by unit test

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine, nunit, code-coverage

I've got this method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Moves piece to location, does not verify that this is a valid move
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dest"></param>
public virtual void Move(Coordinate dest)
{
    if (Board.IsPieceAtLocation(dest))
    {
        if (GetAllPossibleKills().Any(p => p.BoardLocation == dest))
        {
            Board.KillPieceAtLocation(dest);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new LocationOccupiedException("Board location already occupied and kill is not valid",this, Board.GetPieceAtLocation(dest));
        }
    }
    BoardLocation = dest;
}
```

And it's covered by two unit tests:

```
[Test]
public void LocationOccupiedTest()
{
    Board board = new Board();
    board.GenerateNewGamePieces();
    Assert.Throws<LocationOccupiedException>(()=>board.GetKing(false).Move(new Coordinate(0,0)));
}

[Test]
public void KillPieceTest()
{
    Board board = new Board();
    board.GenerateNewGamePieces();
    Piece knight = board.GetPieceAtLocation(new Coordinate(1, 0));
    knight.Move(new Coordinate(1,4));
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(()=>knight.Move(new Coordinate(0,6)));
}
```

According to the coverage analysis, the whole method is covered except for:

`if (GetAllPossibleKills().Any(p => p.BoardLocation == dest))`

You can see the coverage status next to each line of code:

[image: Coverage Screenshot]

I don't understand how that can be the case given both branches of the if statement are traversed.

How can I get this covered?

Comment: So `Board.KillPieceAtLocation(dest);` is covered?

Comment: Yeah, by `KillPieceTest` => `knight.Move(new Coordinate(1,4));`

Comment: No, I mean you literally put a breakpoint on the line of code and checked it got hit when running the unit tests? Did you check that?

Comment: Your test cases that go into the `else` - are they because `GetAllPossibleKills` is empty or because they have values but the `p.BoardLocation == dest` checks are all false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that you are not testing all possible execution paths for the `Any`.

You may need to add extra test cases to ensure you cover (for example) moving illegally when there are other valid targets (thanks for the example @Persistence).

---

To fix this specific example, you'd need to add a test case for moving to an occupied space that isn't a valid kill target when there are other valid kill targets.

```
[Test]
public void MoveToOccupiedWithOtherValidTargets()
{
    Board board = new Board();
    board.GenerateNewGamePieces();
    Piece king = board.GetKing(true);
    king.Move(new Coordinate(0,5));
    board.GetPieceAtLocation(new Coordinate(0,1)).Move(new Coordinate(0,4));
    Assert.Throws<LocationOccupiedException>(()=>king.Move(new Coordinate(0,4)));
}
```